# PyImport_Import isn't working with BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE after changing form py2 to py3

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-2.7, boost-python

I am working on updating an embedded Python2.7.14 interpreter to an Python3.9.7.

Here is my problem, the interpreter is used for scripting in a c++ programm. For scripting there is an internal libary called _internal. It's defined by using Boost 1.7.0:

```cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(_internal)
{
    python::def("foo", foo);
}
```

With the py2 it worked to import the libary like this

```cpp
void init_ConvertCString();
extern "C" void init_internal();

/.../

    static CString strPath(Common::Path::GetShortPath(Common::GetApplicationPath()));
    Py_SetProgramName(strPath.GetBuffer());
    strHome(Common::Path::GetShortPath(Common::Path::Normalize(Common::GetApplicationPath()+"..\\Runtime\\Scripting\\")));
    Py_SetPythonHome(strHome.GetBuffer());

    Py_Initialize();


    init_ConvertCString();

    init_internal();
    
    PyObject* module = ::PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString(_T("sys")));
    PyObject* _internal = ::PyImport_Import(PyString_FromString(_T("_internal")));
    if (module)
        PyObject_SetAttrString(module, _T("stdin"), _internal);
```

But sadly for reasons i am not able to work, out it's not working on py3 anymore. I replaced all the py2 functions for py3 ones:

```cpp
void init_ConvertCString();
extern "C" void PyInit__internal();

/.../


    static CString strPath(Common::Path::GetShortPath(Common::GetApplicationPath()));

    static CString strHome(Common::Path::GetShortPath(Common::Path::Normalize(Common::GetApplicationPath()+"..\\Runtime\\Scripting\\")));
    Py_SetPythonHome(CA2W(strHome.GetBuffer(), CP_UTF8));


    Py_Initialize();
    init_ConvertCString();

    PyInit__internal();
    
    PyObject* module = ::PyImport_Import(PyUnicode_FromString(_T("sys")));
    PyObject* _internal = ::PyImport_Import(PyUnicode_FromString(_T("_internal")));
    if (module)
        PyObject_SetAttrString(module, _T("stdin"), _internal);
```

The function

```cpp
::PyImport_Import(PyUnicode_FromString(_T("_internal")));
```

is returning null. All the paths stayed the same.

Is there somthing i missed? After a few hours of debugging i start to lose my sanity.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to make it run again:

1. change the datatype from void to an PyObj

```cpp
extern "C" PyObject * PyInit__internal();
```

2. added befor the `Py_Initialize();` the line

```cpp
    PyImport_AppendInittab("_internal", &PyInit__internal);
```

now the module can be loaded.